# How do I print certain text for a specific IP address from a file and repeat the process for multiple texts and IP addresses?

Tags: bash, automation, adb, ui-automation

I'm automating the process of customizing multiple boxes/devices. The following bash script reads IP address from a file called device_ips.txt -> connects to one device -> runs the adb commands -> disconnects the device -> connect to next IP address and repeats the process.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  ip_file="device_ips.txt"
  if [ ! -f "$ip_file" ]; then
    echo "Error: $ip_file not found."
    exit 1
  fi

  # Read the IP addresses from the file into an array
  mapfile -t device_ips < "$ip_file"

  for device_ip in "${device_ips[@]}"; do
    device_ip=$(echo "$device_ip" | tr -d '\r')  # Remove any Windows-style carriage return characters

    if [ -z "$device_ip" ]; then
      echo "Error: No IP address found in the file."
      exit 1
    fi

    adb disconnect

    adb connect "$device_ip"

    connected=$(adb devices | grep "$device_ip" | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ "$connected" != "device" ]; then
      echo "Error: Connection to $device_ip failed."
      continue
    fi

    # Commands to be executed
    adb root
    adb remount
    adb install...
    # rest of adb commands...

    #LOGIN
    email_file="emails.txt"
    mapfile -t email < "$email_file"
    while IFS= read -r email; do
      email=$(echo "$email" | tr -d '\r')
      adb shell input tap 886 337 # Taps on empty textbox where email has to typed
      for ((i=0; i<${#email}; i++)); do
        adb shell input text "${email:i:1}" # types email
      done
      adb shell input tap 930 549 # login
    done < "$email_file"

    wait

  done

done
```

device_ips.txt file contains IP addresses in this format:

```
192.168.0.123
192.168.0.132
192.168.0.146
```

It works well in picking up the next IP address from the file and customizing the devices one by one. The issue I'm facing is with the Login process (below **#LOGIN**). The code is supposed to pick up emails one by one the same way it does for IP addresses but it keeps  repeating the first email (id_1@email.com) on all devices and doesn't move to second email or to third email.

emails.txt contains the email IDs:

```
id_1@email.com
id_2@email.com
id_3@email.com
```

I tried changing third line below #LOGIN which was `while IFS= read -r email; do` to `for email in "${email[@]}"; do` and it prints all emails together in textbox like: `id_1@email.comid_2@email.comid_3@email.com` and repeats the same thing on all the devices.

What I want is it types `id_1@email.com` on IP address `192.168.0.123` then `id_2@email.com` on `192.168.0.132` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read both files into arrays, and then use a `for` loop to iterate over array indexes so that you can retrieve the email address from the same index as the ip address you're currently processing. Something like:

```
ip_file="device_ips.txt"
email_file="emails.txt"
mapfile -t device_ips < "$ip_file"
mapfile -t email_addresses < "$email_file"

for (( i=0; i<${#device_ips[@]}; i++ )); do
  echo "device ip: ${device_ips[i]}"
  echo "email: ${email_addresses[i]}"
  echo "---"
done
```

Running this code will produce output like:

```
device ip: 192.168.0.123
email: id_1@email.com
---
device ip: 192.168.0.132
email: id_2@email.com
---
device ip: 192.168.0.146
email: id_3@email.com
---
```